# Using a global variable as parameter to Mail::IMAPClient

Tags: perl, imap

I'm trying to make a mail bulk downloader with perl, that will connect on multiple accounts and download it´s attachments, but i´m still learning this language. I´m having an issue with credentials stored in a text file reading. Whenever i pass the parameters as string, i can connect to my account and retrieve information about unread emails. Snippet:

```
my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
  Server   => 'mail.example.com',
  User     => 'nicolas',
  Password => 'password',
  Uid      => 1,
) or die "Erro ao conectar na conta";
```

It connects, and using `my @mails = ($imap->unseen);` with a `foreach` loop i can get all my unseen mails on a list.

However, if i try to get my credentials from a file and assign to a variable and further use this variable as credentials to `$imap` it fails:

```
foreach my $line ( @lines ) {
  my @credentials = split( /\s+/, $line );
  my $domain = $credentials[0];
  my $account = $credentials[1];
  my $password = $credentials[2];

my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
  Server   => 'mail.example.com',
  User     => $account,
  Password => $password,
  Uid      => 1,) 
}
```

When i run the script i get this message:

```
$ ./folder_list.pl
Can't call method "select" on an undefined value at ./folder_list.pl line 43.
```

If i `print "$account", "$password";` i can check its values, but cant use them as parameters of `$imap`. What am i missing here?

Comment: "our" is not what you want, leave that out.

Comment: But is inside a block scope. If i turn into `my` i cant use anywhere unless i declare them at the start of the script

Comment: How many lines do you have in the file? If just one, no loop is needed, just `my $line = <$FH>`.

Comment: Right now, there is only one line, but the intent as i said at the start of my question is to create a bulk downloader. Our company have many emails with different domains.

Comment: @nwildner, why exactly would you need to use them outside this loop? Right now your code is doing something you're hardly intended - detailed in answer.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov. I'll put everything inside the loop to make things easy. Since the file have just one line, it will not matter. I will edit my question also to keep things more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird. Problem solved on `el5`(CentOS) after upgrading perl to `pel-5.8.8-43.el5_11` and the libs to `perl-Mail-IMAPClient-3.37-1.el5` and `perl-Email-MIME-1.903-2.el5.rf`. Don´t know witch of them was causing the problem but, it solved.

Code still the same:

```
  # Faz a conexão com a conta. Se não der certo passa pra próxima
  my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
    Server   => $mailserver,
    User     => $account,
    Password => $password,
    Uid      => 1) or ($log_script->log("$hora: Erro de autenticação na conta $account. Verifique as credenciais") and next);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that there's an empty line at end your file. This loop you have in question loops over all lines and file, remembers *only* last one and then constructs `IMAPClient` with that data. If you construct it with empty account/password you are likely to get errors like those you've mentioned.

Drop `our` and use `my` and move processing into the loop to, because I understand that's exactly what you want - do IMAP processing with every account.

```
foreach my $line ( @lines ) {
    my @credentials = split( /\s+/, $line );
    my  $domain = $credentials[0];
    my  $account = $credentials[1];
    my  $password = $credentials[2];

    my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
        Server   => 'mail.example.com',
        User     => $account,
        Password => $password,
        Uid      => 1,
    )

    # Rest of code for each mailbox
    # ....
}
```

Comment: No. Problem still persists even after adding this block inside the `foreach`

Comment: @nwildner, well post related source with line numbers then. Right now I don't know what exactly line 43 is.