# Text file is moved incompletely to cifs mountpoint with Perl

Tags: perl, debugging, text-files, cifs

Well, this one is the weirdest filesystem related issue i had in a loooooong time.

[I have a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34922871/2231796), that basically connects on a remote imap server, downloads emails, marks them as read, rip-off trash to download only `.txt` and `.xml` files. If `.txt` use [`Text::Unaccent`](http://search.cpan.org/~ldachary/Text-Unaccent-1.08/Unaccent.pm) to remove accents.

This is done on a 1-to-1 relationship of imap remote folder to a local cifs mounted folder on this server. The remove imap download and accentuation handling works just fine.

My problem is: IF i download the file, handle accentuation and move it to a `cifs` mounted directory, the file gets ripped off(last 4 to 10K is missing). If i move it to anoter partition on the same machine, files are moved on a sane fashion(same `md5sum`, same filesize, no changes noticed by `diff`).

The chunk of code that does the accents remove and moves the file:

```
      #If file extension = .txt
      if ("$temp_dir/$arquivo" =~ /txt$/i){

         #Put file line by line inside array
         open (LEITURA, "$temp_dir/$arquivo");
         @manipular = <LEITURA>;
         close LEITURA;

         #Open the same file to writing with other filehandler
         open (ESCRITA, ">", "$temp_dir/$arquivo");
         foreach $manipula_linha (@manipular){
           # Removes & and accents
           $manipula_linha =~ s/\&/e/g;
           $manipula_linha = unac_string("UTF-8", $manipula_linha);
           print ESCRITA $manipula_linha;
         };
      };

      # copy temp file to final destination. If cifs = crash
      # move also does not work...
      copy   "$temp_dir/$arquivo", "$dest_file";
      unlink "$temp_dir/$arquivo";
```

Cifs version:

```
[root@server mail_downloader]# modinfo cifs
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.18-409.el5.centos.plus/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
version:        1.60RH
description:    VFS to access servers complying with the SNIA CIFS Specification e.g. Samba and Windows
license:        GPL
```

Perl version:

```
[root@server mail_downloader]# perl --version

This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i386-linux-thread-multi
```

Unaccent version:

```
[root@server mail_downloader]# rpm -qa | grep Unaccent
perl-Text-Unaccent-1.08-1.2.el5.rf
```

**Question:** Any clues on why perl `move` or `copy` have this behavior with a cifs mountpoint and how to solve this?

Obviously i cant post the files contents here, cause they are EDI related stuff, and have some financial info.

Also, if i comment the perl `copy` handle the file myself after unaccent is done using `cp` or `mv`, the file is moved correctly to the `cifs` mountpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is really obvious - you're not closing the file once you've finished writing to it. When you copy/move it to the other file system, you lose a chunk of it that hasn't been synced to disk.

```
     open (ESCRITA, ">", "$temp_dir/$arquivo");
     foreach $manipula_linha (@manipular){
       # Removes & and accents
       $manipula_linha =~ s/\&/e/g;
       $manipula_linha = unac_string("UTF-8", $manipula_linha);
       print ESCRITA $manipula_linha;
     };

     # Flush the file
     my $old_fh = select(ESCRITA);
     $| = 1;
     select($old_fh);

     close ESCRITA;
  };

  move   "$temp_dir/$arquivo", "$dest_file";
```

Comment: Well. Shame on me. I had this unaccent function written on other script for testing purposes, and i forgot to port `close ESCRITA` to this one. Guess you are right.

Comment: After receiving emails with 4 `.txt` files, the problem reproduces again. I guess its not related ONLY with file closing. No `dmesg` messages about cifs being unavailable...

Comment: The problem isn't with the cifs - it's the local file system buffering writes. I'd expected closing the file would cause it to flush the contents to disk, but it sounds like it needs a bit of help. I've updated my answer with a method of flushing the file that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm not proud of doing this, but it's a workaround that pretty much eliminates the cifs bug by not using perl to handle this file move.

Instead of using `move` and `copy` from perl, ill use the operating system `mv` binary through `system` function.

Old chunk of code:

```
copy   "$temp_dir/$arquivo", "$dest_file";
unlink "$temp_dir/$arquivo";
```

New chunk of core:

```
system("/bin/mv", "$temp_dir/$arquivo", "$dest_file" );
```